# Time diff calculations where date and time are in seperate columns

Tags: datetime, mysql

I've got a query where I'm trying to get the hours in duration (eg 6.5 hours) between two different times.

In my database, time and date are held in different fields so I can efficiently query on just a startDate, or endDate as I never query specifically on time.

My query looks like this

```
SELECT COUNT(*), IFNULL(SUM(TIMEDIFF(endTime,startTime)),0) FROM events WHERE user=18
```

Sometimes an event will go overnight, so the difference between times needs to take into account the differences between the dates as well.

I've been trying

```
SELECT COUNT(*), IFNULL(SUM(TIMEDIFF(CONCAT(endDate,' ',endTime),CONCAT(startDate,' ',startTime))),0) FROM events WHERE user=18
```

Unfortunately I only get errors when I do this, and I can't seem to combine the two fields into a single timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure your problem is that your concatenated values are being sent to `TIMEDIFF()` as strings rather than DATETIMEs.  Try calling the `DATETIME` function on them:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), IFNULL(SUM(TIMEDIFF(DATETIME(CONCAT(endDate,' ',endTime)),DATETIME(CONCAT(startDate,' ',startTime)))),0) FROM events WHERE user=18
```

I don't have a MySQL DB in front of my to test that, but I think that or some similar form of it is what you are looking for.  There's an example of it in the MySQL docs involving `MICROSECOND`:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html

Edit: Hmm... looks like TIMEDIFF is supposed to work with strings. Worth trying anyway.

Answer (score -1):

```
TIMEDIFF(endDate,startDate) + TIMEDIFF(endTime,startTime)
```

Comment: Thanks James, I ended up having to use HOUR(TIMEDIFF(endDate,startDate) + HOUR(TIMEDIFF(endTime,startTime), as the way you outlined it gave 8000 as a response instead of 8

Comment: No problem. You would lose the fractional part with that though. I don't have an installation of mySQL to test, how about SUM(TIMEDIFF(endDate,startDate),TIMEDIFF(endTime,startTime))